# PhpStorm: add username for TODOs

Tags: ide, phpstorm

Is it possible to add system username like in `Preferences > Editor > File and Code Templates > Includes tab > PHP File Header`?

```
/**
 * Created by ${PRODUCT_NAME}.
 * User: ${USER}
 * Date: ${DATE}
 * Time: ${TIME}
 */
```

to ToDo section?

Example:

```
// ToDo-Viktor: Some text.
```

Comment: How do you create such ToDo comment?

Comment: It's possible to create comment in ```Editor > TODO```. But I can create ```ToDo``` with my name only hardcoded in ```pattern``` section. I want to
 be able to use system variables like in annotation section, which explained in my question above.

Comment: No -- ToDo patterns are specific to the system .. so it makes little sense to have them depend on system user name (I mean -- to do it dynamically) So ... in `Settings/Preferences | Editor | TODO` you have to use hardcoded name. My question though was about "how you creating that ToDo entry in the actual code" -- I thought you wanted that part to be dynamic.

Comment: From this side you are 100% right. I thought about custom ```todo``` like mix    with annotation, so you only need to write ```//*``` for example and then ```Ctrl + Space``` and autocomplete will add ToDo with specific name.

Comment: Just create Live Template (e.g. `//t` as abbreviation -- seems very natural -- at very least I'm suing it) and then use `user()` function for `$USER$` variable -- if done correctly the current system user name will be inserted automatically -- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2017.1/live-template-variables.html

Comment: Thanks for help it's work for me. Lately  I will post complete answer with my setup to share with others.

Answer (score 2):

You can go in `Settings->Editor->Live Templates` choose `PHP` press on `+` on the right and create an abbreviation.

e.g.

Abbreviation: mytodo

Description: whatever you want

the in the Template text: `// ToDo-$USER$` - be careful to have a $USER$ set or you can choose other variable in here.

To the variable $USER$ it can be assigned an expression, by clicking on `Edit variables`. And because you need the User for your case you should use `user()`. (LE see comment @LazyOne)

Choose for which format should this be available by clicking on `Define`.

Then you can write in your editor `myt+tab` and voilà.

Comment: If you want to have current user name inserted automatically (like it's done in File Template) then why typing it manually at all? Just use `user()` function in Live Template for that. I mean -- just putting `$USER$` is not enough (unless you are happy to type user name manually)

Comment: you can set for each variable an expression - so yes for this case should be set to user(). I will update my answer with this extra info.

Comment: Need to edit variable using button ```Edit variables``` and put ```user()``` to the expression section.